# How does Tacacs server forward the credentials from client to Authentication server?

Tags: cisco, authentication, tacacs, authorization

How does Tacacs server forward the credentials from client to Authentication server?

Does a decryption and Encryption of creds takes place? Or is it just a packet forward ?

Edit: The authentication server, i refer to would be a LDAP server to which tacacs would forward the credentials.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. The TACACS server IS the authentication server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> RADIUS was designed to authenticate and log dial-up remote users to a
>   network, and TACACS+ is used most commonly for administrator access to
>   network devices like routers and switches.

http://www.tacacs.net/docs/TACACS_Advantages.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Taccas server will always be in sync with organization LDAP server.

**Let assume cisco switch is login from taccas server**

1. TACCAS ip address Configuration need to configure on cisco switch
2. when user is entering login credentials, authentication request traffic will forwarded towards TACCAS server .
3. TACCAS server will validate credentials of user . Because  LDAP server is always in SYNC with TACACS.